# Sorting in swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

```
var arr:Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = [["title":"Mrs","name":"Abc"],["title":"Mr","name":"XYZ"]]
arr.sort { (<#[String : String]#>, <#[String : String]#>) -> Bool in
        <#code#>
    }
```

I have an array of dictionaries with the data format as represented above. I want to sort this array by **name** key. I did it in older swift like:

```
arr.sort{$0.name < $1.name}
```

which is not working anymore. Please let me know how to move ahead with this structure and sort it.

Thanks.

Comment: Am I the only one who is thinking about "@MartinR is coming!!"? :)

Comment: Dot notation does not work in *older swift* either.

Comment: I agree, can't see when it can work. I would use if let to catch name value, but if you want something short `arr.sorted { $0["name"]! < $1["name"]! }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array of dictionaries of the form `[String: String]`
and a dictionary does not have a `name` property, so
`$0.name` is invalid (in *any* Swift version).

Retrieving the dictionary value is done via subscripting, 
e.g. `$0["name"]`, which returns an *optional*.
In Swift 2 you could compare optionals directly (and `nil` was
considered "less" than any non-`nil` value). Therefore in Swift 2
you could sort the array with

```
arr.sortInPlace { $0["name"] < $1["name"] }
```

However, the optional comparison operators have been removed in
Swift 3 with the implementation of
[SE-0121 – Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md).

Therefore you have to unwrap `$0["name"]`.
If you are 100% sure that every dictionary in the array has a "name" key
then you can unwrap forcefully
as [Ahmad F suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40973320/1187415)

```
arr.sort { $0["name"]! < $1["name"]! }
```

If that is not guaranteed then provide a default name, e.g. the empty string via the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
arr.sort { ($0["name"] ?? "") < ($1["name"] ?? "") }
```

Example:

```
var arr = [["title":"Mrs","name":"Abc"], ["title":"Mr","name":"XYZ"], ["title": "Dr"]]
arr.sort { ($0["name"] ?? "") < ($1["name"] ?? "") }
print(arr)
// [["title": "Dr"], ["name": "Abc", "title": "Mrs"], ["name": "XYZ", "title": "Mr"]]
```

As one can see, the dictionary without a "name" key is ordered first.
A simple way to sort entries without name *last* would be:

```
arr.sort { ($0["name"] ?? "\u{10FFFF}") < ($1["name"] ?? "\u{10FFFF}") }
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. In case of the key is not guaranteed to be "name", is there a way to let ["title": "Dr"] (or all dictionaries with no "name" key) to be at last of ordering?

Comment: @dfri: Is that the case? The sort is not stable.

Comment: @MartinR you're right, `""` vs `""` will naturally "suffer" from the non-stable sorting, my bad x)

Comment: @MartinR can you provide me your knowledge source? As I checked in the docs and there were none like that. It would be of much more help if I can learn them myself too.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I'm not pretty sure if `arr.sort{$0.name < $1.name}` worked in "older swift", however, it should be like:

```
var arr:Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = [["title":"Mr","name":"XYZ"], ["title":"Mrs","name":"Abc"]]

print(arr) // [["name": "XYZ", "title": "Mr"], ["name": "Abc", "title": "Mrs"]]

arr.sort {
    ($0["name"])! < ($1["name"])!
}

print(arr) // [["name": "Abc", "title": "Mrs"], ["name": "XYZ", "title": "Mr"]]
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: This was in older swift. Doesn't work in swift 3. Please have a look at expected syntax.